# Liquibase sql generated error with column comments?

Tags: liquibase

When I add a new column comment , liquibase give me an error sql. How can I fix it ?

xml like :

```
<databaseChangeLog xxxxxxxx>
    <changeSet author="root (generated)" id="1574189348049-1">
        <setColumnRemarks columnName="nickname" remarks="nickname" tableName="t_user"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

sql like :

```
ALTER TABLE testdb.t_user COMMENT = 'nickname';
```

Comment: Liquibase Version: 3.8.1

Comment: What was the exact error message?

Comment: @SteveDonie there was no error message

Comment: Then whats wrong with the sql?

Comment: @Jens I want to change column remarks, but the sql change the table remarks

Comment: Ah. OK. When writing up a problem report, always good to say "this is what I did (steps), this is what actually happened, and this is what I expected to happen". 
Now the only thing we are missing is what version of Liquibase you are using and what database platform. It does seem like a bug, but without knowing what the database is, hard to tell for sure. Some DBs don't even support column comments.

Comment: @SteveDonie Sorry about too little information I left. The database I used was MySQL 5.7.26, and the liquibase command version was 3.8.1. At the same time, I also tried the Java API, which is also 3.8.1, and got the same result

Comment: mysql 8.0.18 got the same result

Comment: This appears to be a bug. I've opened https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3516 to track it.

Comment: @SteveDonie I tried to read the source code and modify it.And then I found MySQL do not have the function that only modify the remark but data type, so it seems to merge the two functions of SetColumnRemarksChange and ModifyDataTypeChange into one.